# How to past multiple list from ajax to Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have an issue which I want to get all the data from `list`, so I want to loop every single data from selected items and insert it to database,
currently it returns the data like this when I print it `['[object Object]', '[object Object]']`,
how can I insert these data one by one? or just print it one by one?

**I have this list** which is selected_items I loop the data and then pass it to ajax

```
selected_items = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {        
     var selected_obj ={ 
        stock_id: checkBoxes[i].id,
        quantity: row.cells[3].innerHTML
      }
      selected_items.push(selected_obj);
}
```

**when console the selected_items** it's just like this

[image]

so now I want to pass these list to django using ajax

```
console.log(selected_items);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'sales-item' %}",
      data:{
        multiple_list: selected_items.join(','), item_size: selected_items.length
      }
  }).done(function(data){...
```

**views.py**

```
out_items = request.POST.getlist('multiple_list[]')
print(out_items)
```

**and it prints like this**

```
['[object Object]', '[object Object]']
```

**Updated Code** how can I loop the data? this is what I tried but it doesn't reflect the data at all

```
multiple_list: JSON.stringify(selected_items)
```

**viesw.py**

```
out_items = request.POST.get('multiple_list')

for i in out_items:
     print(out_items1[i])
```

**how to print or insert it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `selected_items.join(',')` you are taking the `__str__` (or js equivalent) of `{'stock_id': 5, 'quantity': 15}` which just happens to be `[object Object]`

---

So I'd recommend just using Json, which will encode the entire nested list-dict and will be loaded as a normal list-dict in python

#### Javascript

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'sales-item' %}",
    data:{
      multiple_list: JSON.stringify(selected_items),
      item_size: selected_items.length,
    }
}).done(function(data){...
```

##### Python

```py
stock_list = json.loads(request.POST.get('multiple_list'))

print(type(stock_list))
# <class 'list'>

print(stock_list)
# [
#   {'stock_id': 5, 'quantity': 15},
# ]
```

---

#### Edit

Yes!, you'd just loop it like normal nested list-dict

```py
stock_list = json.loads(request.POST.get('multiple_list'))

for stock_list_item in stock_list:
  obj, was_created_bool = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(
    stock_id=stock_list_item['stock_id'],
    quantity=stock_list_item['quantity']
  )
```

**but!** If you **know** you are going to be creating each item, I'd recommend using `bulk_create`

```py
stock_list = json.loads(request.POST.get('multiple_list'))

bulk_create_list = []

for stock_list_item in stock_list:
  bulk_create_list.append(
    MyModel(  # Note: NO .object
      stock_id=stock_list_item['stock_id'],
      quantity=stock_list_item['quantity']
    )
  )

# Creates all items in one query
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(bulk_create_list)
```

---

& extra tidbit

These all work the same! *(quite handy for dynamically creating filters ;) )*

```py
# setup
stock_list_item = {'stock_id': 5, 'quantity': 15}
# ----

MyModel.objects.get_or_create(
  stock_id=stock_list_item['stock_id'],
  quantity=stock_list_item['quantity']
)
# ==
MyModel.objects.get_or_create(**{'stock_id': 5, 'quantity': 15})
# ==
MyModel.objects.get_or_create(**stock_list_item)
```

Comment: I have added updated code above and I've able to implement your code provided but do you know how can I loop every single data ? either stock_id or quantity? All I need is to insert it all to the database

Comment: @BootCamp Edited my answer. You'd just manually loop through it like a normal List